# Q: Using ListView.builder and it showed "ListView.builder(itemBuilder: null)"

Tags: flutter, widget

and i have problem with this issue :

i'd been trying to use ListView.builder but it always shows ListView.builder(itemBuilder: null) since i see others resulting just normal where i expected to show itemCount and itemBuilder : (BuildContext etc.
Pardon my broken english because I am asian. Thank you

````
import 'package:flutter_chat_ui_starter/models/user_model.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  ChatScreen({this.user});

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.user.name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            iconSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(itemBuilder: null),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.builder` requires `itemBuilder`:

Example:

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: 10, // length of the list, optional
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return new Text(litems[index]); // return the view for each items of the listview
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "auto-complete".

Steps:

1. Clear everything inside `ListView.builder(itemBuilder: null)` so you get             `ListView.builder()`.
2. Now place your cursor under the word `ListView` of  `ListView.builder()` and your IDE will show you some issue, just use auto-fix to complete the code for you.
3. For jetbrains IDE like Intellij IDEA or Android Studio the shortcut is `Alt`+`Enter`.If 
   you use VS code it is `Ctrl` + `.`